# How to solve 'The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.' issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, layer

I am trying to use MobileNet for my model
[This is the code snippets from google colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZrjM.png)

I got this error. Could you explain to me what happened and how I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I found it.
Basically you just need to re import the library

```
from keras.applications import MobileNet
```

after that the error just vanished